# Angular2 application development

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-services, node-modules

As i am developing an angular2 application in which am using a service to call a server. At Each time while hitting the server, zone.js which present in node modules also hits the server. what is the main purpose of zone.js and what is the reason for hitting the server and how it can be handled?

Answer (score 0):

`zone.js` is to do with the Angular's internal `change detection mechanism`(new in angular 2). It is required. You can safely ignore it.

To know more about it go to : https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html